# Как структурировать проект, чтобы запускать setup.py test из корневой папки проекта и __main__.py в субдериктории?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Структура моего проекта:

```
project ┐
        ├─ src ┐
        │      ├─ __init__.py
        │      ├─ __main__.py
        │      └─ ...
        ├─ requirements.txt
        └─ setup.py
```

При тестировании через `setup.py` интерпретатор да и pylint думают, что я нахожусь в папке `project` и ожидют, что в src-файлах я буду дописывать к импортам `from src`.

При прямом запуске `__init__.py` наоборот: `from src` вызывает исключение, так как я уже нахожусь в папке `src`.

В `os` искал, как изменить текущую директорию, не нашел. Буду благодарен, если подкинете статью о структурировании проектов и взаимосвязи `setup.py`, `__init__.py`, `__main__.py` и т.п.

Comment: Не надо никаких `src`, каталог с модулем приложения должен иметь имя модуля, то есть в вашем случае это наверно `project`

Comment: А `__init__.py` запускать вообще не надо, и раз вы его зачем-то запускаете, значит делаете что-то не так

Comment: @andreymal я не думаю, что каша из десятка файлов в корневом каталоге проекта - это нормально. А `__init__.py` запускает `main()` в `handler.py` или в исключительных ситуациях просит ввести дополнительные данные.

Comment: Не надо корневой каталог, надо просто переименовать `src` в `project` — получится `project/project/__init__.py`. Вызов `main()` должен лежать в файле `__main__.py`, и этот файл должен запускаться не напрямую, а командой `python -m project` или что-то вроде того. Тогда импорты вида `import project` (сейчас это у вас `import src`, надо каталог переименовать) будут работать нормально всегда и везде

Comment: Это всё тянет на ответ, но на ruSO водятся люди, которые разбираются во всём этом лучше меня, так что я пока подожду. :)

Comment: @andreymal мою проблему не исправило, так как в данном случае я буду запускать `__main__.py`, и ничего не изменится, но за замечание спасибо

Comment: Ещё раз: не надо запускать вообще никаких файлов, надо запускать командой `python -m project` и всё будет хорошо

Comment: @andreymal а как же дебаг, все дела?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53078/discussion-between-andreymal-and-lisovskey).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наличие `src/__init__.py` это ошибка, если `src` не является именем Питон-пакета. Если вы хотите использовать ваш код как `import package` (как правило `project==package`), то следует `src` в `package` переименовать (структура `project/package/__init__.py`). Описывается это, к примеру, [в вводном руководстве (есть русские переводы)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

`package/__main__.py` вы напрямую не должны запускать. Команда для запуска: `python -m package` из корневой папки проекта или из любой папки, если пакет уже установлен (`pip install -e .`). См.  [описание `__main__` в официальной документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html).

При запуске Питон-скрипта, его директория автоматически в pythonpath (`sys.path`) добавляется, поэтому `python setup.py test` команда, которая запускает py.test или похожие инструменты, найдёт ваш пакет `package`.

Подробнее об организации пакетов см. https://packaging.python.org/

Чтобы самостоятельно не создавать скелет проекта каждый раз с нуля, можно сгенерировать папки/файлы из шаблона, используя [`cookiecutter`](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html)—можно свой шаблон использовать или выбрать один из существующих наиболее полно для вашей задачи подходящий шаблон:

```
$ pip install -U cookiecutter
$ cookiecutter gh:audreyr/cookiecutter-pypackage
```

Comment: А как быть если нужно дебажить отдельный файл?

Comment: @lisovskey: что это на русском языке означает? (написали тест, запустили тесты, поправили код, чтобы тесты проходили, повтор -- какой шаг вопрос вызывает?)

Comment: все предельно ясно, спасибо