# Конфликт импортов при запуске python проекта из консоли Ubuntu

Tags: python

Вот мой python проект. ОС Ubuntu.

```
- Project
    - first
        - run.py
    - second
        - packages.py
```

Содержимое run.py

```
from Projcet.second.packages import *

func()
```

Содержимое packages.py:

```
 def func():
    print('result')
```

Запускаю run.py скрипт из консоли в виртуальном окружении.

```
 python3 project/first/run.py
```

Ошибка: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'second'

Я пробовал прописывать __ init __.py, но видимость появилась только в PyCharm. Проект мне нужно запускать из консоли в виртуальном окружении.

Как сделать так, чтобы импорты были видны не используя подобную конструкцию:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))), '../'))
```

Comment: `from Projcet.second.packages import *` - здесь опечатка закралась: `Project` неправильно написано.

Comment: Попробуйте `python -m Project.first.run` вместо `python -m Project/first/run.py`. Если вы рассматриваете папку Питон-пакетом, то добавьте в неё `__init__.py` для ясности. Чтобы из любой папки запускать, установите ваш пакет (создайте setup.py, выполните pop install). Связанные вопросы [Как структурировать проект, чтобы запускать setup.py test из корневой папки проекта и `__main__.py` в субдериктории?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/623709/23044) и [Как запускать файл Python из любого места в Ubuntu?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/507591/23044)